# TTaskDialog.Execute always return True even Cancel is clicked

Tags: delphi

Execute the following code in Delphi XE2/XE3

```
with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do begin
  try
    if Execute then
      ShowMessage('Success')
    else
      ShowMessage('Failed');
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

No mater what button you click to close the dialog, the message shown is always `Success`.

The Delphi documentation written `TTaskDialog.Execute` as

> Use Execute to display the Task Dialog. Execute opens the
>   task-selection dialog, returning true when the user selects a task and
>   clicks Open. If the user clicks Cancel, Execute returns false.

Comment: It seems like it is an implementation bug or the documentation's error.  I have reported the issue to http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111722

Answer (score 13):

It seems which the documentation is not correct, this is the execution flow of the `TTaskDialog.Execute` method :

> TTaskDialog.Execute -> TCustomTaskDialog.Execute ->
>   TCustomTaskDialog.DoExecute -> TaskDialogIndirect = S_OK?

As you see the result of the method `Execute` is *true* only if the [`TaskDialogIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns S_OK.

To evaluate the result of the dialog, you must use the [`ModalResult`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomTaskDialog.ModalResult) property instead.

```
  with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do
  begin
    try
      if Execute then
        case ModalResult of
         mrYes    : ShowMessage('Success');
         mrCancel : ShowMessage('Cancel');
        else
         ShowMessage('Another button was pressed');
        end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Note : if you close the dialog using the close button the `mrCancel` value is returned in the *ModalResult* property.

Comment: Is this consider a design flaw or it is a documentation error?  I personally feel that it is a design flaw as there is no way to make TTaskDialog.Execute return false.